# Regex doesn't work with 1 parameter

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I have an error in my regex, that somebody wrote for me.
I've tried to write my own regex but this is just to hard for me to crack.

I have a custom "tag" like {module:agenda:getlist:params(2)}
But.. if I only have 1 param the regex doesn't see the 2 but gets the wrong code.

This is my regex code

```
$paramcount = preg_match_all('{
        # [^,]+ everything that isn't a comma
        # (?<=...) is a look behind. Meaning that the part that has the 3 dots 
        # becomes matched but not goes through the rest of the regex

        # matches "null" in "params(null"
        (?<=params\()[^,]+

        | # this is the separation dash

        # (?=...) is a look ahead, same as the look behind but than on the end

        # matches "null" in " null)"
        (?<= )[^,]+(?=\))

        |

        # matches "true" in ", true" and ""foo"" in ", "foo""
        (?<=, )[^,]+
    }x', $data, $parammatches);
```

So when I try to match it.. the outcome is:

```
$array = array
    (
        [0] => params(2
    );
```

This is not what i want, i only want the 2 to be matched not the rest.
When i give it more params like this "params(null, 2)" everything works out and i have 2 nice array values.

Can somebody guide me or help me out here.

EDIT:
More output can be found on pastebin.
http://pastebin.com/x0WL9K4u

Comment: What is it exactly that you want ? Extract all parameters passed to the param between parentheses and put them in the array ?

Comment: Yes that i what i want.
Actually i want to get everything between the hooks "params(i-want-these-values)"

Comment: Can you please post more sample input ?

Comment: More output can be found on pastebin. http://pastebin.com/x0WL9K4u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody answerd my question.
He wrote an update for my regex problem

```
<?php
$str = 'params(null, true, "Foo", null)';

preg_match_all('{
# [^,]+ betekend alles wat geen komma is
# (?<=...) is een look behind. Dit betekend dat het gedeelte op de 3 puntjes
# gematched moet worden voor de rest van de regex, maar dat hij niet meegenomen
# wordt in de match

# matches "null" in "params(null"
(?<=params\()[^,]+

| # dit is het scheidingsteken

# (?=...) is een look ahead, zelfde als look behind maar dan voor erachter

# matches "null" in " null)"
(?<= )[^,]+(?=\))

|

# matches "true" in ", true" and ""foo"" in ", "foo""
(?<=, )[^,]+
}x', $str, $matches);

$params = $matches[0];
?>
```